# doctrine altering uuid column on every migration

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

i have a question if anybody faced this kind of issue. Ive been searching for solution but i didn't find.

Every time i generate migration with doctrine, i see in migration files:

```
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
  $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE verification ALTER id TYPE UUID');
  $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE verification ALTER id DROP DEFAULT');
}


public function down(Schema $schema): void
{
  $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE verification ALTER verification_id TYPE UUID');
  $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE verification ALTER verification_id DROP DEFAULT');
}
```

these are my annotations:

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UuidGenerator::class)
 *
 * @Groups({"read"})
 **/
 private UuidInterface $id;
```

I use postgress image: postgres:13-alpine
and  "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",

framework
"api-platform/core": "^2.6",

I've tried previous versions of doctrine-migrations-bundle along with postgres:12

Those alters are being added on every migration. I've checked my local db, drop it, remove docker volumes. Then i start containers again, run migration to be sure i got correct db schema. Problem still occurs.
I don't know what cause this issue. Maybe some of you have some idea what i can look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have 1.7.0 version of ramsey/uuid-doctrine extension in your composer.lock, because it really has a bug with generating schema.
Which was fixed a just few days ago: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine/pull/165

So try downgrading to 1.6.0:

```
composer require ramsey/uuid-doctrine:1.6.0
```

(or upgrading to the latest dev version)

### Explanation

The reason why doctrine keeps generating migration for altering the uuid column, is that the custom type class (which is `Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidType`) misses the requiresSQLCommentHint flag (in 1.7.0):

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

This flag tells doctrine to use a comment on the field to determine which custom type the values from this field need to be hydrated into. In case of Ramsey UuidType the comment should look like this: `(DC2Type:uuid)`

As a quick workaround, you can even just add the comment manually (without upgrading the ramsey/uuid-doctrine package):

```
   COMMENT ON COLUMN verification.id IS '(DC2Type:uuid)'
```

or via migration:

```
   $this->addSql('COMMENT ON COLUMN verification.id IS \'(DC2Type:uuid)\'');
```